# C++ Template Class Specialization

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, visual-c++, template-specialization

I have a template class that is a data structure where all but one of the functions should behave the same if the data put into the data structure is a pointer or not. However, when I want to sort the data in the data structure, I want the function to behave differently whether it is a pointer or not. Do I have to reimplement the entire class as a template specialization for pointers or could I just implement two friend functions for sorting and the compiler will choose the proper one depending whether the input is `DataStructure<T>` or `DataStructure<T*>`? If the latter how should I go about doing this.

Comment: With sufficiently modern compilers, you could use [constexpr if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If). Barring that, have the method delegate to a helper class template, then partially specialize that template.

Answer (score 0):

Either way works.
I believe duplicating only the sort functions would be easier.
Here's an example. Hope it helps.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


class Sorter
{
public:
  template <typename T>
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<typename T::type>::value, void>::type
  sort(T & data)
  {
    cout<<"sort pointers\n";
  }
  template <typename T>
  typename std::enable_if<!std::is_pointer<typename T::type>::value, void>::type
  sort(T & data)
  {
    cout<<"sort non pointers\n";
  }
};

template<typename T>
class DataStructure
{
public:
    using type = T;
};

int main() {
    Sorter s;
    DataStructure<int> d1;
    DataStructure<int*> d2;
    s.sort(d1);
    s.sort(d2);
    return 0;
}
```